# TypeScript : Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'

Tags: typescript

I declared a variable `x` as

```
public x : 0;
```

Instead of initialising it to `0`

Thinking that I had declared it correctly, I initialised it like

```
this.x = 5;
```

I was getting error on the above line, which read

```
Type '5' is not assignable to type '0'.ts(2322)
```

Can anybody tell, why is this happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature of Typescript, after the `:`  the possible type(s) are declared and that could be specific values also.

For example you could also limit variables to specific strings:

```
var action : "email" | "sms";
```

In this case `action = "fax"` will give a compile error.

With strings this is called "String Literal Types". With numbers this is called "Numeric Literal Types".

So in you case you declared it a numeric literal type with `0` as allowed value.

See also https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types

So beware of mixing `=` and `:` in Typescript, as both are correct Typescript in this case but have different behavior ;)